# Let $\phi:R[X] \rightarrow S[X]$ be a unital ring homomorphism. Prove if $f(x) \in R[X]$ is reducible, then $\phi(f(x))$ is reducible.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R,S$ be integral domain and let $\phi: R \rightarrow S$ be a unital ring homomorphism. Define $\Phi:R[X] \rightarrow S[X]$ such that $\Phi(\displaystyle{\sum_{i=0}^m r_i X^i}) = \displaystyle{\sum_{i=0}^m \phi(r_i) X^i} $. Prove if $f(x) \in R[X]$ is reducible in $R[X]$ and $f(x)$ is monic, then $\phi(f(x))$ is reducible in $S[X]$.

However, I think I have found a counter example for this statement. Consider $\phi: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_p$ such that $\phi(x) = \bar{x}$. Then $9x^2-1 = (3x+1)(3x-1)$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Z}$ but $\Phi(9x^2 -1)= 1$ is not reducible in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. What is wrong with this counterexample.

Can someone give me some hint on how to proceed?

Comment: How do you define 'reducible'? If you require it to have a non-trivial factorization, then this isn't true in general. Let $R = S = k$ be a field, and consider $\varphi : k[x] \to k[x]$, $f(x) \mapsto f(0)$. Then $x^2 - 1$ is reducible, but its image is not.

Comment: @AymanHourieh sorry edited

Comment: Hint:  This requires so little that any substantive hint would pretty much be a full answer.

Comment: @WillO my idea is that if f(x) is reducible then f(x) = g(x)h(x) and so$ \phi(f(x) = \phi(g(x) \phi(h(x)$ but i can't figure out how to show that $\phi(f(x))$ and $\phi(g(x))$ are not units. does g(x) not unit implies that $\phi(g(x)$ not unit? I think it should be but I can't figure out how to show

Comment: @user2675516:  Hint  $S$ is an integral domain, so any unit in $S[X]$ must have degree zero.

Comment: @WillO i am not sure if this is correct. There is this theorem that says . $f(X)=a_0+a_1X+a_2X^2+⋯+a_nX^n$ is a unit in $R[X]$ if and only if $a_0$ is a unit in $R$ and $a_1$,$a_2$,…,$a_n$ are all nilpotent in R. Hence, $\phi(a_0)$ is a unit if  $a_0$ is a unit since if $a_0$ is a unit there exists $b$ such that $a_0 b = 1$, so $\phi(a_0)\phi(b) = \phi(1) = 1$, so $\phi(a_0)$ is a unit. On top of that $a_i$ is nilpotent implies $\phi(a_i)$ is nilpotent since $a_i^n = 0$ implies $(\phi(a_i))^n = 0$ using the multiplicative property of homomorphism. This solves my problem above.

Comment: @user2675516: There are no nontrivial nilpotents in an integral domain.

Comment: @WillO how is this supposed to help me? is there anything wrong with my argument?

Comment: @user2675516: Your argument is fine but it is overkill. For an integral domain, the only units in $R[x]$ are the units in $R$.

Comment: @WillO i still can't figure out how i can use the degree argument to solve this problem? Does the homomorphism preserve degree? I don't think so. Consider $\Phi Z \rightarrow Z_p$. $\Phi(7x) = 0$

Comment: @user2675516:  If $f$ is reducible, then $f=gh$ with $g$ and $h$ monic, and (at least) one of them --- say $g$ --- of degree greater than zero.  The image of $g$ is therefore of degree greater than zero.  Done.

Comment: @WillO why is g and h be monic?http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1237750/must-factors-of-a-monic-polynomial-over-an-integral-domain-be-monic and you are assuming that degree is preserved after homomorphism which i think is not true. see my example above

Comment: @user2675516:  Try proving these (nearly obvious) lemmas:  1)  If $f$ is monic, so is any factor of $f$.  2)  If $g$ is monic, then $\phi(g)$ has the same degree as $g$.  (I am using "monic" to mean "leading coefficient a unit", not "leading coefficient equals 1.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your “counterexample” is not a monic polynomial.

A nonzero polynomial is usually called *reducible* if it is not invertible and can be written as a product of two lower degree polynomials.

If $f$ is monic, then $\phi(f)$ is also monic and of the same degree as $f$. If $f$ is reducible, then the two lower degree factors can be chosen monic. Notice that the homomorphism $\phi$ doesn't reduce the degree of monic polynomials. Thus, if $f=gh$ is the product of two lower degree monic polynomials, $\phi(f)=\phi(g)\phi(h)$ is too.

Why can the lower degree factors be chose monic? Suppose $f=gh$. If $a$ is the leading coefficient of $g$ and $b$ is the leading coefficient of $h$, then the leading coefficient of $gh$ is $ab=1$. Therefore we can consider $g_1=a^{-1}g$ and $h_1=abh$; then $g_1$ and $h_1$ are monic and $g_1h_1=gh=f$.